# How do I merge multiple radial gradients onto a single SVG alpha mask?

Tags: svg

My application uses SVG to render a virtual tabletop scene. The user can place tokens on top of the scene and the background is revealed for a given radius around the token. Tokens can reveal different radii.

Initially I used clip paths to reveal circles around the tokens with hard edges. This works nicely with no issue.

Now, I wonder if I can create "smooth" transitions from revealed to unrevealed by using, for example, a circle with a radial gradient (from white in the center to black to the edges) and use the combined circles as a mask to apply to the scene.

My attempt uses a single radial gradient definition and multiple `<circle fill="url(#gradient")>` within a `<mask>` which is then applied to the underlying image. However as you can see in the image below, the gradients do not smoothly blend into each other.

[These radial gradients do not merge nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6ybN.png)

I understand **why** this is happening but I'm looking for another way to achieve the effect with SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify your gradients with alpha rather than black/white and this works just fine. (Please post test code in future)

```html
<svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
  <radialGradient id="myGradient">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="100%"/>
  <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="100%"/>
  <stop offset="60%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="60%"/>
  <stop offset="95%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0%"/>
</radialGradient>

<mask id="myMask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <circle cx=".25" cy=".25" r=".25" fill="url(#myGradient)"/>
  <circle cx=".25" cy=".55" r=".20" fill="url(#myGradient)"/>
        <circle cx=".65" cy=".35" r=".35" fill="url(#myGradient)"/>
</mask>
  </defs>
  
  <image href="https://nostalgiacentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/snakesladders5.jpg" x="10" y="10" height="200" width="200"  mask="url(#myMask)" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
  
</svg>
```